# java - list environment variables of a running process

Tags: java, environment-variables

Is there an easy way to list environment variables of some running java process?

It's easy to check JVM arguments and system properties using jvisualvm, but it does not show environment.

Comment: Which operating system? PS this question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: On Windows procexp, on Unix ps.

Comment: @RobinGreen "this questions has nothing to do with Java" is the reminder I needed! thanks :D

Comment: From inside java code you can print `System. getenv()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is provided by the operating system and is not specific to Java processes. As @agbinfo noted, on Windows use procexp, on Linux/Unix use ps. The specific ps command to use is:

```
ps e -ww -p 1234
```

where 1234 is the PID of your Java process.

Comment: True, but different processes could have been started with different environment variables in their scope/context given the scripts that ran and exported environment variables by the session that started the process in question. If I ssh into a machine, I only see the environment variables that were loaded via scripts associated to my session.

Comment: @SamMalayek I've added the specific command to use to my answer. You appear to have misunderstood my answer - I did not instruct people to look at the current environment variables with "set" or something like that.

Comment: that command just blew my mind. Thanks for updating your answer! They’re associated to the process!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Spring Boot application then the environment variables are exposed via /env endpoint as systemEnvironment.